# Quais os efeitos positivos e negativos para o command timeout 0 na conection string postgres?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Olá, eu estava recebendo constantemente esse erro

```cs
Response/Exception: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. - System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
```

Então eu pesquisei um pouco sobre e coloquei na minha default conection string o comando timeout=0;

O erros pararam, mas estou com duvidas se isso pode ser prejudicial para a minha aplicação.
Seria correto a se fazer ou me equivoquei? tem outra maneira de corrigir?

Comment: Do manual: "connect_timeout: Zero, negative, or not specified means wait indefinitely.", portanto você precisa garantir de alguma outra forma que não existirão erros de conexão que levem a uma espera infinita. Será que especificar um tempo máximo que julgue razoável esperar não seria mais conveniente?

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado!